# Prove that $m^2+n^2=q^2\iff m=3,n=4,q=5$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, pythagorean-triples

[image]

Hi

Can someone please give me an idea where to start with this ?

Thanks
Steve

Comment: Consider $$m^2 + (m+1)^2=(m+2)^2$$ and solve for $m$.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE. Please indicate what you have tried and where you are stuck. This will help people better tailor their answer to your background and situation. It will also demonstrate that you are interested in your question and not just looking for someone to do your homework for you - Math.SE is not a homework site.

Comment: Hi,Why do we want to put it in terms of m?

Answer (score 3):

$$ m^2 + n^2 = q^2 \implies m^2 + (m+1)^2 = (m+2)^2
$$
Expanding,
$$ 2m^2 + 2m + 1 = m^2 + 4m + 4 \implies m^2 - 2m - 3 = 0
$$
What does this polynomial tell you?

Comment: Hi,Why do we want to put it in terms of m?

Comment: Also it tells you it crosses the x axis at 3 and -1... which is what i had last night.  But im still struggling to see the proof?

Comment: @SteveRichrds The point is that $m$ has to be $3$(being a positive integer) for this equation to hold, which implies $m^2 + (m+1)^2 = (m+2)^2$ only has $1$ solution.

Comment: @SteveRichrds It could have been in terms of $m$ or $n$ (as shown in lfh's answer) or $q$, the point is that we want to get an equation with a single variable

Answer (score 2):

$$
m^2 + n^2 = q^2 \implies (n-1)^2 + n^2 = (n+1)^2
$$
which simplifies to
$$
n^2=4n
$$